# Saving entity with PagingAndSortingRepository.save produces both @PostUpdate/@PostCreate events if there is a child collection initialized

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data Rest in my application and found some inconsistent behavior.

I got a Parent entity like

```
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity = Child.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

And a Child with a parent reference

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
Parent parent
```

When I do parentRepository.save(Parent.builder().build()) I get https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9940

But when I do

`parentRepository.save(Parent.builder.children(Collections.emptyList()).build())`

then I receive both a

```
@PostPersist
public void onCreate(Object entity) {
   ...
}
```

and a

```
@PostUpdate
public void onUpdate(Object entity) {
   ...
}
```

event that breaks my domain logic.

I am trapped for the resolution of this... Am I doing something wrong? Why storing a parent with empty list of childs send both a create and an update event for the parent object?

**EDIT**: I receive the same object (Parent) in both listeners. The only query appeared in logs is an INSERT, no trace of update. Is like INSERTing into db triggered an extra phantom PostUpdate

Comment: What Object types do you get in onCreate and onUpdate? Both Parent.class?

Comment: Yes, with same hash, event the PersistenceBag representing childrens collection. Its exactly same entity